# CMD warning: "Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated"

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda

I installed Anaconda (added to path) but when I try to run Python from the cmd, I get the following message:

*Warning:*

> This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environment please see https://conda.io/activation_

I followed the link and tried to activate the environment, but my cmd then changes to (base) mode, which I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: Related: *[Python is in a Conda environment, but it has not been activated in a Windows virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679132/)*

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps

1)open cmd and type
"conda activate base"

2)then type python

Which will satisfy your problem

Comment: 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Earlier versions of conda introduced scripts to make activation behavior uniform across operating systems. Conda 4.4 allowed conda activate myenv. Conda 4.6 added extensive initialization support so that conda works faster and less disruptively on a wide variety of shells (bash, zsh, csh, fish, xonsh, and more). Now these shells can use the conda activate command. Removing the need to modify PATH makes conda less disruptive to other software on your system. For more information, read the output from conda init --help.

One setting may be useful to you when using conda init is:

auto_activate_base: bool