# Conda environment is activated, but Python console says the environment has not been activated

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda

I am trying to follow the documentation provided by Anaconda as well as their [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#windows-environment-has-not-been-activated). The problem still persists however.

I see similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59664294/anaconda-environment-has-not-been-activated) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56623269/cmd-warning-python-interpreter-is-in-a-conda-environment-but-the-environment-h), however the details are where my problem differs and anyway, the answers provided do not work for me.

I am working on a corporate server, where I have administrator rights, but where I do not have access to the Internet.

- OS: Windows Server 2016 (v10.0.14393)
- Anaconda: V2020.02 py37_0
- Conda: V4.8.2

The Anaconda installation was done as an administrator and the not-recommended option of adding to PATH was enabled. This is how my PATH looks like at the moment (redacted entries are company specific and not relevant here):

[image: System PATH]

The following are the Conda-specific steps that I ran from **Anaconda Prompt (PowerShell)**:

1. `conda create --prefix ./envs --offline`: Create a Conda environment with --prefix and --offline flags. This is to create the environment within my project root folder (in an offline manner).
2. `conda activate D:\conda_project\envs`: Activate the environment
3. `conda install \path\to\numpy\tar\from\conda-forge`: Install [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) in the activated virtual environment
4. `python`: Run Python console

And this is where I can't just seem to get rid of the warning:

> This Python interpreter is in a Conda environment, but the environment has not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environment please see https://conda.io/activation

I have verified that the Conda environment is activated based on the appearance in the shell and based on `conda info --envs`:

[image: Verified that environment is activated]

Finally, here is the screenshot of the error that I reported (in a Python console):

[image: Python console thinks the Conda environment is not activated]

I have also gone through a similar process by trying to setup a Conda environment using the --name flag instead of the --prefix flag (so it creates the environment in Anaconda's `env/` folder). The result has been the same.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Related: *[Python is in a Conda environment, but it has not been activated in a Windows virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679132/)*